# Ошибка при открытии фрагмента на реально устройстве

Tags: android

При запуске приложения на эмуляторе всё работает. Решил протестировать приложение на телефоне (версия 4.4.2),при вызове следующего фрагмента вылетает ошибка. Что может быть не так?

Profile:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {

    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private TextView profileName;
    private TextView profileEmail;
    private TextView profilePhone;
    private CircularImageView photo;
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    public Profile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        profileName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        profileEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        profilePhone = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_phone);
        photo=(CircularImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        setData();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView-Profile");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_edit:
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){

                        Fragment fragment=new EditProfile();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
                        Log.i(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected");
                    }
                }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
                return true;
            default:
                // Not one of ours. Perform default menu processing
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }


    public void setData(){

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        profileEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").child(user.getUid());
        StorageReference myRefImage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()+"/img.jpg");
        myRefImage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(photo);
            }
        });
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ProfileUserInfo userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileUserInfo.class);
                if (userInfo == null) {
                    profileName.setText("");
                    profilePhone.setText("");
                } else {
                    profileName.setText(userInfo.getName());
                    profilePhone.setText(userInfo.getPhone());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "setData");
    }

}
```

Xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:siBorderColor="@color/tw__solid_white"
            app:siBorderWidth="6dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_name"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_email"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.09"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_phone"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 21906
                                                                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02008a
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2354)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:425)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:129)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:186)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:197)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:508)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1160)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:234)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:292)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1047)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1074)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Ещё такие ошибки выскакивают во время работы приложения,но они особо на работу программы не влияют:

```
Writing exception to parcel
                                              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15168)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
                                                  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
                                                  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                                  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я надеюсь

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Он же пишет

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: ...
this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

ну так дай этот пермишн.